# Customer group ID not sent on admin email after registration in Magento

Tags: php, email, magento, transactional

I'm having problem when sending Transactional Email after customer register on the system, I need to show the group of the user registration as I have module for Wholesale registration and the group ID as well as password is sending only on customer email and not on the admin email as shown on the images attached.

This is the email sent to customer
[image]

This is the email sent to admin
[image]

Why they are not sending with the same content?

Comment: Maybe some problem with the context (wrong store_id) - it is hard to say. Paste source code of that email template. It could help to find a root of this problem.

Comment: <!--@subject Welcome, {{var customer.name}}! @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"htmlescape var=$customer.name":"Customer Name",
"store url=\"customer/account/\"":"Customer Account Url",
"var customer.email":"Customer Email",
"var customer.groupId":"Customer groupId",
"var customer.group.name":"Group Name",
"htmlescape var=$customer.password":"Customer Password"}
@-->
this is for group_id:
   <p class="highlighted-text">   Group: {{var customer.groupId}}</p>

Comment: Hmm, you can try to use {{var customer.getGroupId()}}. It should be determined the group id on fly. I'm not sure but maybe it does help you.

Comment: Sorry no luck, only on registered customer the email is OK but on the admin email is not OK. Are there some permissions for customer info not to be sent twice or ? It is strange on one email the same template is sending all of the data as it should and on other email the data is not complete ex. password and group ID are missing?

Comment: ??? Can someone help me?